# Move a project without destroying assembly reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

We setup our assembly references as project references.  I am reorganizing source control, moving projects here and there.  When I open my solution the project references are broken.  I have to remove the references and re-add them.  Doing this removes the project reference from all assemblies.

Is there a way to correct the project reference in the solution file without removing and re-adding projects?

I could go into MSBUILD and do it, but there's no unload option for my solution...so that seems like a pain.  Any native way to fix this common issue?  Since the files are in the same solution, I expect the project references to resolve themselves automatically.

This way I don't have to correct all my references manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do this just only once - Resharper could help you to do this a bit faster.

Whenever it finds broken reference - it will offer option "reference assembly X and use class Z". Probably not the best way cause it still involves manual file plumbing, but this could SLIGHTLY reduce mouse clicks and file tree navigation. Though, you still need to remove wrong reference manually.